# Rutherford scattering experiment error

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran90, fortran95

I'm very new to Fortran and have to simulate the Rutherford Scattering experiment for an assignment. In the code, there is a gold nucleus assumed to be at the center (x,y) = (0,0). I'm trying to find the acceleration, velocity and then distance of the alpha particle based on the Coloumb's Law. r_lim is meant to be the boundary condition which, when the particle passes, the loop is meant to stop successfully.  Please let me know if I can explain anything else.

```
PROGRAM rutherford_scatter

IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE particle

REAL:: x,y

END TYPE particle

TYPE(particle):: r_alpha, v_alpha, a_alpha
REAL:: x_0,y_0, v_0, q_gold, q_alpha, k_e, m_alpha, c, c_frac, time_step, r_lim
LOGICAL :: check = .FALSE.

k_e = 1.0
c = 137.053999
time_step = 1.0 *10.0**(-5.0)
q_alpha = 2.0
q_gold = 79.0
m_alpha = 7294.3

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter initial value for x distance.'
READ (*,*) x_0
y_0 = -0.005

WRITE (*,*) 'Enter initial value for velocity (fraction of speed of light).'
READ (*,*) c_frac
v_0 = c_frac * c

r_alpha%x = x_0
r_alpha%y = y_0

r_lim = 1.1 * SQRT(r_alpha%x**2+r_alpha%y**2)


v_alpha%x =  0
v_alpha%y = ABS(v_0)

OPEN (11, FILE = 'assign_11.out')
DO WHILE (check)
    a_alpha = acceleration(k_e, m_alpha, q_gold, q_alpha, r_alpha)
    v_alpha = velocity (v_alpha, a_alpha)
r_alpha = distance (r_alpha, v_alpha)
    WRITE (11,*) r_alpha
    IF (r_alpha%x .GT. r_lim .OR. r_alpha%y .GT. r_lim) THEN
        check =.TRUE.
    END IF
END DO
CLOSE(11)


CONTAINS

TYPE (particle) FUNCTION acceleration (k_e, m_alpha, q_gold, q_alpha,r_alpha)
TYPE (particle), INTENT(IN):: r_alpha
REAL, INTENT (IN)::k_e, m_alpha, q_gold, q_alpha
acceleration%x = (k_e/m_alpha) * ((q_gold * q_alpha)/(ABS(r_alpha%x))**2 )* (r_alpha%x/SQRT(r_alpha%x**2+r_alpha%y**2))
acceleration%y = (k_e/m_alpha) * ((q_gold * q_alpha)/(ABS(r_alpha%y))**2 )*(r_alpha%y/SQRT(r_alpha%x**2+r_alpha%y**2))
END FUNCTION

TYPE (particle) FUNCTION velocity (v_alpha, a_alpha)

TYPE (particle), INTENT (IN):: a_alpha, v_alpha

velocity%x = v_alpha%x + a_alpha%x*time_step
velocity%y = v_alpha%y + a_alpha%y* time_step
END FUNCTION

TYPE(particle) FUNCTION distance (r_alpha, v_alpha)
TYPE (particle), INTENT (IN):: r_alpha, v_alpha

distance%x = r_alpha%x + v_alpha%x * time_step
distance%y = r_alpha%y + v_alpha%y * time_step
END FUNCTION

END PROGRAM rutherford_scatter
```

Comment: We are not expert in your physical problem. Please speak about the details of your program and explain what exactly happens. How do you compile? Which input do you provide? What does the program print?

Comment: Try : do while(.not.check)